# Is there a good citation for the impact of inelastic neutron scattering on the measurement of the intramolecular geometry of H2O?

Tags: water, molecular-structure, neutrons

I have tried to find a good citation for the experimental measurement of the intramolecular geometry of H2O in the liquid phase and come across a problem:

It seems that the method of choice for such a problem is the use of elastic neutron scattering/diffraction and that this exact method cannot be applied to liquid water due to the properties of protons, specifically their nearly identical mass compared to neutrons.

I can find a bunch of Wikipedia references that explain this issue, but, as per usual, there is no usable citation attached to the relevant paragraph. The Wiki article on neutron diffraction states:

"It is undesirable to work with the relatively high concentration of H in a sample. The scattering intensity by H-nuclei has a large inelastic component, which creates a large continuous background that is more or less independent of scattering angle."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_diffraction#Hydrogen,_null-scattering_and_contrast_variation

I remembered that I've heard something similar in regards to the necessity to use heavy water (D2O) instead of regular water in nuclear reactors due to the effect of efficient transfer of momentum from neutrons to hydrogens. Apparently the efficiency of this kinetic energy transfer increases the smaller the differences in mass between two colliding particles/atoms are (neutrons and hydrogens obviously have almost identical masses). So in order to achieve high enough criticality in a nuclear reactor (sustained fission with an average emission of 1 neutron per fission reaction), D2O needs to be used as a mediator because the hydrogens of regular water would absorb the kinetic energy of all emitted neutrons and cause the nuclear reaction to cease.

"Water makes an excellent moderator; the ordinary hydrogen or protium atoms in the water molecules are very close in mass to a single neutron, and so their collisions result in a very efficient transfer of momentum, similar conceptually to the collision of two billiard balls. However, as well as being a good moderator, ordinary water is also quite effective at absorbing neutrons. And so using ordinary water as a moderator will easily absorb so many neutrons that too few are left to sustain a chain reaction with the small isolated 235U nuclei in the fuel, thus precluding criticality in natural uranium."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressurized_heavy-water_reactor

So I know that elastic neutron scattering cannot be done to a high level of precision in liquid water, which is why studies that measure the intramolecular geometry of water using neutron scattering use D2O instead of H2O.
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00268977700103011

And I am pretty sure I've understood why that is. Now: why can't I find a good article or book excerpt to cite for my report to outline this issue as to why comparisons between force field calculations of the water geometry and experimental data are an issue?

Can anyone find what I can't?